# Error initializing a boost udp socket with a boost io_service

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, runtime, boost-asio

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 for my project and I'm a newbie at using boost, so I encountered with a runtime problem trying to initialize this:

```
FClient::FClient(const std::string & logName, const std::string & logPassword, udp::endpoint hostpoint) : mSocket(mService), mLogName(logName), mLogPassword(logPassword), mEndPoint(hostpoint)
{

}
```

Where mSocket is a boost udp socket, and mService is a boost asio io_service (both private members of FClient), and I guess the rest of the calls (which basically are string inits) are not useful to detect the error. I hope the error is on mSocket(mService) initialization which is of type:

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket(boost::asio::io_service)
```

Visual Studio call stack:
http://pastebin.com/fjwWbhst

I'm using windows 8 with boost 1.5.6 and I'm defining:
-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0602

Thank you,

-lilEzek

Comment: impossible to say without a more detailed example. Can you create a minimal complete example to recreate the problem?

Comment: Show please `FClient` definition (with its members)

Comment: what is the error? Exception thrown? Crash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is old, but I just had a similar issue and came across this post. I figured out the problem was that the socket was being initialized before the IO service was constructed. So when the socket constructor is called with the non-constructed IO service, it causes a segfault.

In C++, the order of construction of class members is determined by the order they are listed in the class declaration (usually in the .h file). So if, `FClient` is declared like this:

```
class FClient
{
    // ...
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket mSocket;
    boost::asio::io_service mService;
    // ...
};
```

You get the a segfault during construction of `FClient::mSocket`. The fix is to swap the order of `mSocket` and `mService`:

```
class FClient
{
    // ...
    boost::asio::io_service mService;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket mSocket;
    // ...
};
```

This ensures `mService` is constructed before being passed to the `mSocket` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to close this question as I fixed it doing mSocket a pointer, and initializing it somewhere else. Thank you anyway for the help given.